# Cant draw outside original size pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I created an image with pygame, filling the whole window

[image: Green circle]

With the pygame.VIDEORESIZE event, I redraw the image with the new size. But it only draws where the original image was, and leaves a white "margin"!
[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: Full project is at https://github.com/titoco3000/PygameUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. What you need to do is recreate the screen on every resize event, with the new size:

```
if event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
                self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((event.w, event.h), pygame.RESIZABLE)
```